# req.file is not populated but, req.body is using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, multer

I'm trying to upload an image to a NodeJS server using multer and express for a React Native app following this example : 
https://github.com/expo/image-upload-example/blob/master/backend/index.js

But it does not seem to work and I really don't know why...
I'm using axios for http requests.

**Client side:**

```
    const uriParts = image.split('.'); //image is the uri
    const fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', {
      image,
      name: `photo.${fileType}`,
      type: `image/${fileType}`,
    });


    axios.post(`${Utils.userServerUrl}/edit_profile`, { formData })
      .then((response) => {
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(`response : ${response}`);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

**Server side:**

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log(req.body.name) 
    cb(null, 'profile_imgs/')
  },                    
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname)
  }                     
});                     

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/', upload.single('photo'), (req, res) => {
  const {formData} = req.body;
  console.log(formData);
  if(!req.file) console.log('no files uploaded');
  else console.log('file uploaded!');
})
```

I've already tried adding those options :

```
let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  };
```

to the axios method but I get a **Error: Multipart Boundary not found**

If anyone could help me I would be pleased... thanks

**[EDIT] SOLUTION :**

After struggling for a while I finally found the solution, if anyone is interested.

**Client side:**

```
function uploadImageAsync(uri) {

    const serverUrl = `${Utils.userServerUrl}/edit_profile`;

    const uriParts = uri.split('.');
    const fType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];
    setFileType(fType);


    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', {
      uri,
      name: `${profile.username}.${fType}`,
      type: `image/${fType}`,
    });

    axios.post(serverUrl, formData) //I didn't encapsulate formData in an object
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      });

  }
```

**Server side:**

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'images/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/', upload.single('photo'), (req, res) => {
  if(!req.file) {
    res.send('No file uploaded !')
  }else{
    res.send('File uploaded successfully !')
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with FormData, but after looking at the documentation i don't think the arguments you are passing into the formData.append function are correct.  The second argument should be of type `File` but you are passing in an Object. What is the variable `image` in that object?

Comment: image is the uri (i.e comment), however the example is taken from expo's github so I don't think that that is what is going wrong.

Comment: Where's the example on their github? Only example of upload i found is using `File` like this `data.append('file', document.getElementById('file').files[0]);` Which is correct way to uplaod a file. https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/examples/upload/index.html

Comment: here : https://github.com/expo/image-upload-example/blob/master/frontend/App.js

Comment: Is anyone having problem making this work on Android?

It works perfectly on ios, but the file skips mutler and is being added to the request body as a string (content of the image)

Answer (score 0):

In the client, send the FormData as the body of the request:

```js
const formData = new FormData()

// photo is a Blob, filename is a string
formData.append('photo', photo, filename)

const response = await axios.post(url, formData)
```

On the server, read the data from  `req.file`:

```js
router.post('/', upload.single('photo'), (req, res) => {
  // use req.file.buffer in multer v1, req.file.stream in multer v2
})
```

Comment: I found the solution and edited my post, thank you !

Comment: Is anyone having problem making this work on Android?

It works perfectly on ios, but the file skips mutler and is being added to the request body as a string (content of the image)